# Using regular expression to remove space and numbers

Tags: regex, excel

I have a column of data in excel that appears as follows:

```
aast<space>1<space>
qusw<space>3<space>
umw<space>18<space>
arst<space>50<space>
```

I will like to remove the numbers to have just the following:

```
aast
qusw
umw
arst
```

I tried regexp in both excel and notepad2++ to get this done without any success using the following:

```
^\s+[09]\s+$
```

Can someone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider Text to Columns on that column with space as the delimiter and then just delete all columns but the first.

Or use a formula such as:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! The problem was solved using excel function "Text to Columns". Really appreciate your help! Many thanks pnuts.

Comment: I will take note of that pnuts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead remove what you don't need.  Replace

```
[0-9 ]*
```

with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*)\s[0-9]+\s
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/Sdb5PwzeTB)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 String regex = "[^\\s0-9\\<\\>\\s]";
```